# Problem with circle on tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I have a problem with this graphic.

[image]

The circle does not focus on the corresponding number. For example, in the first line you should focus on number one, but the top of the circle just touches it.
Attached images of how it should look:
[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
grid={both}, grid style={solid,black!50}, 
clip=false,
y axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
x axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
xmin=-0.75,xmax=10.5,  ymax=1.1,ymin=-0.12, 
ytick={0,0.1,...,1.1},
xtick={0,1,...,10},
extra y ticks={-0.12,1.1},extra x ticks={-0.75,10.5},
extra y tick labels={},extra x tick labels={},
extra y tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},extra x tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},
%minor tick num=1, % added
ylabel={$|S(n\cdot \omega_{_{0}})|$}, xlabel={$f$},
ylabel style={above},  % changed
xlabel style={right}, % changed
yticklabel style={fill=orange!20,circle,inner sep=0.75pt},
xticklabel style={fill=orange!20,circle,inner sep=2pt},
scale only axis,
width=16cm,
height=7cm
]
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,blue] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(1,0)(1,0.6366)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(2,0)(2,0.3183)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(3,0)(3,0.2122)};
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(4,0)(4,0.1591)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(5,0)(5,0.1273)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(6,0)(6,0.1061)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(7,0)(7,0.0909)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(8,0)(8,0.0795)};
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(9,0)(9,0.0707)}; 
\addplot[-*,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(10,0)(10,0.0636)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Armónicos de la función $g_{(t)}$}

 \end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please, give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Look up ycomb plots in the pgfplots manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With use of the `ycomb` macro from the `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=12cm, height=11cm,
    axis lines=center,
    grid={both},
    axis line style={thick,-Stealth},
    ycomb,  % <---
    xmin=-0.9,xmax=10.5,  ymax=1.08,ymin=-0.1,
    ytick={0,0.1,...,1.1},
    ylabel=$|n\cdot\omega_{0}|$, 
    xlabel={$f$},
    xlabel style={right}, % changed
    ticklabel style={circle, fill=orange!20, font=\footnotesize, 
                     minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0pt},
    every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick}    
  ]
    \addplot+[blue] coordinates {(0,1)};
    \addplot+[red, mark=*] coordinates {
                (1,0.6366) (2,0.3183) (3,0.2122) (4,0.1591) (5,0.1273)
                (6,0.1061) (7,0.0909) (8,0.0795) (9,0.0707) (10,0.0636)
                                       };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, Zarko!!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of options in the `axis` environment made me dizzy. Anh here is a plain TikZ solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=6]
\draw[gray!50] (11,0) grid[ystep=1mm] (0,1.1);
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(11,0) node[below]{$f$};
\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(0,1.1) node[above]{$|S(n\cdot\omega_0)|$};

\foreach \i/\ivalue in 
{1/.6366,2/0.3183,3/0.2122,4/0.1591,5/0.1273,6/0.1061,7/0.0909,8/0.0795,9/0.0707,10/0.0636}
\draw[red,line width=1.5pt] 
(\i,\ivalue) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]{}--
(\i,0) node[below=3pt,circle,fill=pink,text=black,scale=.7,minimum size=22pt]{$\i$};

\draw[blue,line width=1.5pt] 
(0,1) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]{}--(0,0);

\foreach \j in {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1}
\path (0,\j) node[left=8pt,fill=pink,circle,scale=.7,minimum size=22pt,inner sep=1pt]{$\j$};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{center}
\lipsum[10] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1  --`A lot of options in the axis environment made me dizzy`   ha ha !!

Answer (score 1):

In your incomplete example, the filled circles are drawn by an arrow tip (of which the definition is not shown). For an arrow tip, "the top of the circle just touches it" is the expected behavior.

In the following example, filled circles are drawn by marks (documented in [manual of `pgfplots`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf), section 4.7.1), hence solves the problem.

To further improve your plots,

- you might need to use `minimum size=...` in `yticklabel style`;
- some explicitly specified extra ticks seem strange and useless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
  x mark/.style={
    mark=*,
    mark indices=2
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    grid={both}, grid style={solid,black!50}, 
    clip=false,
    y axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
    x axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
    xmin=-0.75,xmax=10.5,  ymax=1.1,ymin=-0.12, 
    ytick={0,0.1,...,1.1},
    xtick={0,1,...,10},
    extra y ticks={-0.12,1.1},extra x ticks={-0.75,10.5},
    extra y tick labels={},extra x tick labels={},
    extra y tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},extra x tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},
    %minor tick num=1, % added
    ylabel={$|S(n\cdot \omega_{_{0}})|$}, xlabel={$f$},
    ylabel style={above},  % changed
    xlabel style={right}, % changed
    yticklabel style={fill=orange!20,circle,inner sep=0.75pt},
    xticklabel style={fill=orange!20,circle,inner sep=2pt},
    scale only axis,
    width=16cm,
    height=7cm,
  ]
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,blue] coordinates {(0,0)(0,1)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(1,0)(1,0.6366)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(2,0)(2,0.3183)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(3,0)(3,0.2122)};
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(4,0)(4,0.1591)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(5,0)(5,0.1273)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(6,0)(6,0.1061)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(7,0)(7,0.0909)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(8,0)(8,0.0795)};
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(9,0)(9,0.0707)}; 
    \addplot[x mark,ultra thick,red] coordinates {(10,0)(10,0.0636)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]